# EF 5 Database First using custom validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

In order to experience the new features of Entity Framework I created a new MVC 4 internet application.
 I connected it to an existing database and generated the Model classes with the dbContext generator.

By running the application I got some validation errors while editing a form. As example for a DateTime field the system was complaining if the date was inserted as "12/10/2012" instead of 2012-10-12 (as in the SQ Server notation). 
I tried to find the validation code in the project, but I could not find it anywhere in the generated code.

One of my model classes is the following:

```
public partial class Artist
{
    public Artist()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public virtual Countries Countries { get; set; }
}
```

How can I customize the validation errors if using the Database first approach? 
If I decor the models with my validation attributes, then they would be erased once the model classes are generated again.

Moreover in a "real world" project where the use of an existing database is mandatory, what would be the best approach with the development of the model classes? 
Extending the classes automatically generated by adding partial classes with the same name?

EDIT (Introduced part of the View):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Movie</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: What does your view look like?  There should be no problem entering a date in MM/DD/YYYY format, as this is converted to a DateTime in .net before it's sent to SQL Server.  Thus, you must be doing something a bit wonky in your view.  Unless you're trying to enter a date in DD/MM/YYYY format, in which case it's a globalization issue which is a totally different problem.  The example you gave should not have given any validation error, though, since it's valid either way (though obviously may not give the results you want if using DD/MM/YYYY)

Comment: You can add validation constraints using the Fluent API:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx

Comment: @millimoose - those constraints will only work on the database, not on MVC validation.

Comment: What date format are you using?  And are you certain that 12/10/2012 creates an error? because either way it should pass validation.  Now, something like 15/10/2012 is a different story.

Comment: If you want answers, Luca.. I suggest answering the questions people ask of you, otherwise what's the point?

Comment: Sorry Mistere Man, I missed your questions. I am using Jquery DatePicker that uses the dates in the format dd/mm/yyyy (I have locally such a time format). I guess the problem might reside in the expected date format (probably set somewhere in the default validation) and the date format inserted in the input. 04/17/2012 creates a validation error while 2012-17-04 is accepted.

Comment: I know the topic is old, but I'm wondering if the same approach would work with the custom attributes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can always use a metadata class

```
public partial class ArtistMetaData
{
   [Required]
   [StringLength(20)]
   public string Name;//it can be a field instead of a property, must just have the same name and type than in your Model class
}
```

and a partial class

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ArtistMetaData)]
public partial class Artist {
}
```

Or (my preferred solution) you can use an external Validation library, like the excellent [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)

You have a "basic" validation by default (which can be removed in the global.asax), checking : that the non nullables values... are not null (like a default Required attribute), and that values are of the right type.

Comment: +1 - I find the metadata class an elegant solution.
In Global.asax I cannot find any method about validation. Is this the only place where I could look at?

Comment: @Luca you have nothing in Global.asax, but you can explicitely DO things on the "implicit" providers in `application_start`, for example by setting the `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes` Property to false (and you won't have the default message "Property xxx should not be null", or something like that, when trying to put null in an int Property)

Comment: I added it and set its value to false, but still the message appears. It is related to the date format, since by entering it in the "SQL Server" format (yyyy-mm-dd) it passes the validation.

Comment: @Luca yes it's not the same problem (AddImplicit... just give a message if you set a null into a non nullable). For your problem, you could maybe look at a CustomModelBinder, which could bind DateTimes from different format to a correct DateTime.

Comment: Today I ran again the project and used jQuery date picker for the dates fields and the application was accepting the date format without complaining. Strange is, I did not change anything in the system since yesterday, therefore I guess there were some property/setting not set during the build. Thanks for the helpful suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Check your browser and machine culture settings and then the jquery validation cultures.

I tend to have this problems since I have the Spanish config, but mvc comes with the English dates and currency formats, etc. For example dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy

You could also use a regular expression attribute to validate the field as you wish.